# Is the poset $\mathrm{Idl}_{\neq \emptyset, P}(P)$ of nonempty, proper ideals in a finite connected poset $P$ (empty or) weakly contractible?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, posets, simplicial-complexes

$\DeclareMathOperator\Idl{Idl}$Let $P$ be a finite, connected poset with at least two elements, and let $\Idl_{\neq \emptyset, P}(P)$ be the set of downward closed sets $S \subset P$ such that $S \neq \emptyset$ and $S \neq P$, ordered under inclusion.

**Question:** Is $\Idl_{\neq \emptyset, P}(P)$ weakly contractible?

**Notes:**

- If $P$ has less than two elements, then $\Idl_{\neq \emptyset, P}(P)$ is empty. If $P$ is a discrete poset with $\geq 2$ elements, then $|\Idl_{\neq \emptyset, P}(P)| \simeq S^{|P|-2}$. Hence the restriction to connected posets with $\geq 2$ elements.
- If $P$ has four elements $a,b < c,d$, so that $|P| \simeq S^1$, then $\Idl_{\neq \emptyset, P}(P)$ has 5 elements arranged in an "$X$" shape, and is weakly contractible.
- In general, if we add $\emptyset$ and $P$ back in, the poset $\Idl(P)$ of all ideals is always contractible (for at least 4 reasons -- it has an initial *and* a terminal object, *and* binary meets *and* binary joins). Similarly, $\Idl_{\neq \emptyset}(P)$ and $\Idl_{\neq P}(P)$ are contractible if $P \neq \emptyset$.
- I checked a few random examples with Sage, which at least turned out to have vanishing reduced homology. (Although I'm not sure how much I trust my code!)

Comment: (Finite) distributive lattices are well known to be shellable. Does that answer your question?

Comment: For example, see Corollary 3.2 of Björner's "Shellable and Cohen-Macaulay partially ordered sets" (https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1980-0570784-2)

Comment: @SamHopkins I'm not sure. $Idl_{\neq \emptyset, P}(P)$ is not necessarily a lattice -- the "meet" of two elements might be empty / their "join" might be $P$. On the other hand, I'm not terribly familiar with shellability or Cohen-Macaulayness of simplicial complexes, but it apparently doesn't imply being weakly contractible. So maybe you were suggesting a _negative_ answer?

Comment: Don't worry about $\varnothing$ and $P$: when studying the topology of lattices it is common to implicitly remove the maximal and minimal elements (because these are cone points, as you note). The homotopy type of a distributive lattice is then known to be either a ball or a sphere. See the classical paper of Björner referenced above or https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.5311.

Comment: Regarding your restriction to *connected* $P$, see Theorem 3.7 of the paper of Hersh and Meszaros: if $P$ is connected (and has $\geq 2$ elements), then the whole distributive lattice $J(P)$ will not be a join of atoms, so in fact the homotopy type of $J(P)$ is that of a ball.

Comment: @SamHopkins I see, thanks, Hersh and Meszaros' 3.7 completely answers my question! If you make this an answer, I will happily accept!

Comment: Yes I answered; but their work is not needed really, you just need a Mobius function computation for this last bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me be a little more historical. As mentioned, it is well known that (open intervals of) distributive lattices are shellable. This is mentioned in Corollary 3.2 of Björner's classic paper "Shellable and Cohen-Macaulay partially ordered sets" (https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1980-0570784-2) but is an older result I believe.

The homotopy type of a shellable complex is a wedge of spheres (of the same dimension). How many spheres do we get? By a basic homology computation, we get $|\mu(\hat{0},\hat{1})|$ of them, where $\mu$ is the Möbius function and $\hat{0}$/$\hat{1}$ are the minimal/maximal elements of the lattice. In a distributive lattice $J(P)$ of order ideals, the Möbius function is given by
$$\mu(I,I') = \begin{cases} (-1)^{\# I' \setminus I} &\textrm{if $I' \setminus I$ is an antichain}, \\ 0 &\textrm{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$
See e.g. Example 3.9.6 of Stanley's EC1, 2nd ed. So your restriction to connected $P$ with $\geq 2$ elements gives $\mu(\hat{0},\hat{1})=0$, hence the open interval $(\hat{0},\hat{1})$ in $J(P)$ is a (homotopy) ball.

Comment: So in fact you don't even need that $P$ is connected, just that it is not a disjoint union of points.

Comment: Yeah, that's really surprising, somehow!

Comment: @TimCampion: If you're interested in homotopy types of other lattices, I recommend the "Poset Topology" monograph by Wachs (https://www.math.miami.edu/~wachs/papers/toolnotes.pdf), though it doesn't mention distributive lattices as far as I can tell (perhaps because they are basically topologically trivial as explained here).

Comment: Thanks! This came up in a rather particular setting -- if I haven't messed up too badly, computing the "space of composites" of an $n$-categorical pasting diagram (which, for various definitions of "pasting diagram", is known to be connected, and hoped to be contractible), can be reduced to computing the homotopy type of a poset of ideals like this one. In general, I think it should be not uncommon in higher category theory to be able to reduce some computation to finding the homotopy type of a particular poset, so actually knowing something about how to do that does seem pretty valuable!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof. Let $M$ be the set of minimal elements of $P$, and let $2_{\ne \emptyset}^M$ be the poset of non-empty subsets of $M$. There is an obvious inclusion of posets $2_{\ne \emptyset}^M \hookrightarrow Idl_{\ne \emptyset}(P)$. Assuming that $P$ is not a disjoint union of points, this restricts to an inclusion
$$i\colon 2_{\ne \emptyset}^M \hookrightarrow Idl_{\ne \emptyset, P}(P).$$

There also is a map of posets $$r\colon Idl_{\ne \emptyset, P}(P) \to 2_{\ne \emptyset}^M,$$
which sends an ideal $I$ to $I\cap M$. The composition $ri$ is the identity, while $ir$ is related to the identity by the inequality $ir(I)\le I$ for every ideal $I$. It follows that $i$ and $r$ induce homotopy equivalences of geometric realizations
$$|Idl_{\ne \emptyset, P}(P)| \simeq |2_{\ne \emptyset}^M|.$$
But $2_{\ne \emptyset}^M$ has a maximum element $M$, so its geometric realization is contractible.

Comment: Oh nice! I had been hoping to find some kind of adjointness argument like this. I was trying to work with maximal elements, though, and the condition dual to not being a discrete poset never occurred to me!

Comment: This is essentially an application of Rota's cross-cut theorem.  Here M is the cross-cut.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: yes, and the cross-cut theorem is behind the Mobius function computation mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thanks for the pointer -- it's a shame that there seems to be a bit of a "cultural (and terminological) gap" between the study of simplicial complexes and categorical homotopy theory.

Comment: @TimCampion, Quillen seemed to play both sides successfully.  Anyway many proof use that a Galois connection (aka adjunction) of posets gives an equivalence of categories.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I see how the argument here is very much like the argument in Proposition 2 [here](https://jlmartin.ku.edu/courses/math796-S08/notes0303.pdf), where we compute the Euler characteristic of a finite distributive lattice using the crosscut theorem. But does the crosscut theorem actually tell us anything more than the Euler characteristic? Can we use it to show that the poset is contractible?

Comment: @TimCampion,  there are several versions of the cross-cut theorem. There is a topological one that can be used to get the homotopy type or there is the version in your link that just goes for the Euler characteristic.

Comment: You can find a proof of the topological version here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.1159.pdf#page35 with no originality claimed.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Thank so much!